# Cannot get a wordpress site to run on a local machine

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to wrok locally on a wordpress site, I've already set up Wamp server, I've exported the DB and edited the `wp-config.php` in order to use the local DB, the problem is that when I open the site I can see the theme loaded correctly but the content of the pages doesn't load instead I get a `"404 Error - no page here"`. 
On the console I get some warnings and just one error:

```
POST http://localhost/mysite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 404 (Not Found)
```

It's trying to locate the admin-ajax.php file but it's missing a folder between `mysite` and `wp-admin`, is there a way to fix this problem or do I need to find where the `admin-ajax.php` file is required and edit the path?

Comment: Can you access the administration dashboard at /wp-admin/? If so then your site is working and the problem might be with the theme, which seems to be using AJAX to load page content.

Comment: @Technoh I can't access that page, evey if I type in the url /wp-admin/admin.php it redirects me to the Wamp localhost page and I really have no idea why

Comment: do you have any errors in your log? Did you set up a custom .htaccess? Try deactivating your theme (by removing or renaming the folder) and see if you can load the site with the default theme.

Comment: Where did you export database from ? Are you trying for fresh install or is database exported from another place ? If so, then you have to run few queries for database url updates.

Comment: @Technoh I haven't set up a custom .htaccess and if I rename the folder of the theme nothing loads

Comment: @DpĚN Damn yes that might be one of the problem :D Yes, I've exported the DB, do you have an example on what queries I have to run?

Comment: See answer at bottom

Answer (score 1):

Since your have exported/imported your database I believe the site's URL and the server's file structure have changed. If that is the case, you will need to download a tool such as [Interconnectit's database search and replace script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). You need to put the files in the root folder of your wordpress installation and then access it.

If you don't still have the export I suggest you make a backup of your database before using the tool, just in case.

**Important**: remember to delete the files once you are done using the renaming tool.

Comment: I'll try as soon as I get home, ty :) btw I did some test and after editing 2 values on the DB (from wp-options: siteurl; home) I was able to load the homepage correctly without errors, the only problem is that the other urls doesn't work

Comment: Yeah Wordpress stores *a lot* of URLs and file paths in the tables, you will need to replace them all and there will probably be hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

in  wamp some changes may  need to do.
please follow as:

left click wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
This will open that file in notepad and you can locate the line

## LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Remove # from starting text if present.
Restart wamp

and set/save permalink once

Answer (score 0):

Move to VVV Worpress, is better than WAMP. WAMP lacks of many features, and will not allow to debug accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these queries in SQL Tab. Replace "existing_site_url" with your existing site url that is site_url row and replace with your new URL

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'existing_site_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'existing_site_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'existing_site_url', 'new_url');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'existing_site_url','new_url');
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use RazorSQL or MySQL Workbench to do a find and replace for the URL's (live vs local).